# Laravel Nested Eager Loading how to use eloquent where condition from inside with nested

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm looking for a way to use `where` condition in my laravel eloquent relationship with eager loading.

Here's my code

```
  $data = Model::with(['stage_chatbot'=> function($stage_chatbot){
     $stage_chatbot->select('id', 'customer_id','stage','created_at');
     $stage_chatbot->orderBy('id', 'asc');
  }])->whereIn('hot_leads_id', $getMaxHl)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');

  $data->where('stage_chatbot.stage', 'like', 'sampleValue')->get();
  return $data;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whereHas() eloquent method like this.

```
$data = Model::with(['stage_chatbot'=> function($stage_chatbot){
    $stage_chatbot->select('id', 'customer_id','stage','created_at');
    $stage_chatbot->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}])->whereIn('hot_leads_id', $getMaxHl)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');

$data->whereHas('stage_chatbot', function ($stage_chatbot) {
   $stage_chatbot->where('stage', 'like', 'sampleValue')
})->get();
return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 1):

try this one

using `use` keyword in laravel

```
$searchText = "sampleValue";
$data = Model::with(['stage_chatbot'=> function($stage_chatbot) use ($searchText) {
        $stage_chatbot->select('id', 'customer_id','stage','created_at')
        ->where('stage_chatbot.stage', 'like', "%".$searchText."%")
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}])->whereIn('hot_leads_id', $getMaxHl)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

for more information how to used `use` keyword in anonymous function [see](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

Define a varibale on your Search Input field or value and pass this through **use** on your model query

Try this

```
$search = $request->search;
$data = Model::with(['stage_chatbot'=> function($stage_chatbot) use ($search) {
    $stage_chatbot->select('id', 'customer_id','stage','created_at');
    $stage_chatbot->where('stage', 'like',$searchText);
    $stage_chatbot->orderBy('id', 'asc');
}])->whereIn('hot_leads_id', $getMaxHl)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```