# How can i filter nested object in array using Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

This is json object from database

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "price_role": [
     {"id": 1, price:20, role:"HQ"},
     {"id": 2, price:10, role:"AG"}
   ]
}
```

My question is how to filter a specific price_role by a given role and convert it to an object instead of returning list?

Try using this way but it is not worked :

```
$role = "HQ"; 
$query = Product::with('price_role',  function ($q) use ($role) {
      $q->where('role', '=', $role);
  })
  ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```

Expected output if `$role = "HQ"` :

```
 {
  "id": 1,
  "price_role": {"id": 1, price:20, role:"HQ"},
 }
```

**FYI: I'm using Laravel 5.5**

Comment: your json object have you received it from database, please?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Nested Eager Loading how to use eloquent where condition from inside with nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911650/laravel-nested-eager-loading-how-to-use-eloquent-where-condition-from-inside-wit)

Comment: @digit you just forget to get result, check  my response

Comment: `but it is not working` what exactly is happening now?

Comment: @fyrye he have just created the query without get the result

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih it is not worked..

Comment: @fyrye the reference link does not solve my issue.. I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: check my response again, please

Comment: how you return the result of the query to view, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$role = "HQ"; 
$query = Product::with(['price_role' => function ($q) use ($role) {
     $q->where('role', '=', $role);
}])
->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```

Can you try this?

Comment: You also forgot the square brackets. `[]`

Comment: Nice, Keep coding mate.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to get all of the results with the `get()` method.

your request should be like this :

```
$query = Product::with('price_role',  function ($q) use ($role) {
    $q->where('role', '=', $role);
 })->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```

Comment: It is still not working. I forgot to put get() in my question before.

Comment: can you update your question and put how your return the result of your query to view blade, please